# MVC store collection between jquery requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

what is the best approach to store collection of data between jQuery requests? 
Ex. Firing one method ,it will calculate some big portion of data, and then get this data in another jQuery request, but without saving into db.

Data is collection of some particular class

And this data needs to be stored in controller that i can easily then access it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the data is used.
If it is user specific data it can be appropriate to use session state. However, if it's app wide data it makes more sense to use the Asp.Net cache.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to do some type of deferred approach.

The simple way is something like this

```
var callMeLast = function(data){
    // do something with the data
};

var callMeFirst = function(data){
    // got data to process and when done call callMeLast

    dataProcessor(data, callMeLast);
};

var dataProcessor = function(data, callback){
    // procecss data

    var result = dataAfterProcessing;
    if (callback){
         callback(result);
    }

};
```

Comment: I just edited that data need to be stored in controller not on client side.